# cat contents of file to Teams channel

Tags: curl

How to cat contents of the file in Linux to teams channel using CURL command

```
curl -d @file.txt URL
curl -H --data-binary @FILE.TXT Teams URL
cat file.txt|curl -x POST Teams URL
```

Comment: You want to upload the content from a URL as a file in the Files section of a Channel? If so, have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 3):

To send the contents of a file in Linux to a Microsoft Teams channel using the `curl` command, you can use the incoming webhook feature in Microsoft Teams. This allows you to send a message to a channel by making a POST request to a specific URL.

Here is an example of how you can use curl to send the contents of a file to a Microsoft Teams channel:

1. First, you will need to create an incoming webhook in your Microsoft Teams channel. To do this, follow these steps:

- In Microsoft Teams, click on the "..." button next to the channel name and select "Connectors".
- Scroll down to the "Incoming Webhook" connector and click "Add".
- Follow the prompts to create the webhook and get the URL. Make sure to copy the URL, as you will need it later.

2. Once you have the incoming webhook URL, you can use the curl command to send the contents of a file to the Microsoft Teams channel. For example:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\":\"$(cat /path/to/file)\"}" webhook_url
```

This command will send the contents of the file at /path/to/file to the Microsoft Teams channel as a message. You can customize the message by modifying the JSON data that is sent in the `-d` option.

Note: You may need to adjust the command to fit the needs of your specific use case. For example, you may want to send the contents of multiple files, or you may want to include additional information in the message, such as a custom title or formatting.

Comment: Is there a way to simple pass a subject and maybe additional text in that text object or it has to be card then >?